# Fitting a tetrahedron through the smallest hole

Tags: geometry, 3d

I'm designing a child's toy consisting of a closed box with a hole on top; a unit tetrahedron must fit through this hole.

What is the smallest possible area of the hole?

Currently my hole is an isosceles triangle with base $1$ and height $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ (the distance between the midpoints of two opposite edges), which gives area $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$. With the correct orientation, the tetrahedron is dropped straight through the hole.

Is it possible to do better considering rotations of the tetrahedra during insertion?

Comment: I wonder what is the area of the square hole through which you can drop the tetrahedron. Also, if you design a toy, why not challenging with the minimal square that requires proper tilting of the tetrahedron.

Comment: I think the minimal square would have diagonals of length $1$, which would give area $\frac{1}{2}$. One could also modify the square to be smaller by inserting the tetrahedron halfway, rotating it 90 degrees, and then fitting the rest through to get an area of $\frac{1}{4} + \frac{\pi}{16}$ for the hole. The hole would look like two squares in the first and third quadrants (imagine a cartesian plane) and two quarter circles in the second and fourth quadrants centered at the origin. The side length of the squares and the radii of the quarter circles would both be $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Because you're building an actual object, thickness of material matters (not just planar cross sections), as do vexations such as non-flatness of the cuts, friction coefficients of the box and the block materials, and the fact that if the hole is close to mathematically optimal, the block is liable to go through partway and get wedged. I guess that's all to say: How tightly do you really want the hole to fit the block?

Comment: Nice problem.  The isosceles triangle area of $\sqrt{2}/4\approx 0.3536$ is the best I've seen in the literature (it's described here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925772111000629).  The same question was asked on MO a few years back and did not receive any better answer: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138752/tetrahedra-passing-through-a-hole.

Comment: I think the question of the minimum-area planar hole through which you could pass a tetrahedron while keeping one of the tetrahedron's edges parallel to the plane is interesting.  You have the square of area $1/2$ (no rotation applied), and the square with rounded corners of area $1/4+\pi/16 \approx 0.4463$ described in the comment (90-degree rotation applied all at once)... it seems possible that applying the rotation more gradually might give an even smaller area.

Comment: Thank you for the link @mjqxxxx; it was very interesting reading about other ideas on how to fit the tetrahedron.